# Write/Read file in my iPhone app Shared File

Tags: c#, iphone, file, shared

I wrote an app on my iPhone. It's a more portable and smaller version of my pc software. I activated the File Sharing feature on my app so now I can transfer files through iTunes. But I want my pc software to be able to read or write files to that shared folder on my iPhone without having to do it manually through iTunes.

I have big constraints:

1. I can't use a Jailbroken iPhone/iPod/iPad
2. The vast majority of my customers don't have Internet access (It's a farm management software so even cellular are not available in some area)... :(

I heard there is a way using Manzana and MobileDevice.dll (itunesmobiledevice.dll). I don't really know how to use these dll. I tried to use Manzana a little but I can't access my folder since it's not a jailbroken iPhone.. Can someone help me with a little bit of code example?

Or is there other ways to make my iPhone app communicate with my C# application using the USB cable without internet access or Wifi?

Comment: mirhagk, I downloaded the project but iTunesLib gives you control only on the music part of iTunes. I cannot access the mobile device... If it's not possible to access my app share folder, is my iPhone app, once plugged to the PC, can send or receive thoses files somehow?

Comment: Just tested iPhoneExplorer and I can browse every folders on my iPhone (non-jailbroken) without any trouble! So, using the iTunes COM/API seems to be the right solution. All I need now is some code example on how to connect to my iPhone, browse folders and read/write files to it using that API..

Answer (score 2):

[mobiledevice.codeplex.com](http://mobiledevice.codeplex.com). This project should let you send and retrieve files from the phone

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest seeing if you can use the iTunes scripting interface. Add the COM reference iTunes 1.1 Type Library to a project and you can control many parts of itunes automatically. I can't find the documentation for it, but you can play around with the library and see if there is something to access the file sharing section.

Here's a decent introduction to using it:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7723/Controlling-iTunes-through-COM